# Are TAP and async/await meant to be used for dedicated threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, async-await, task

I have some number of threads dedicated to one task (receive and handle requests) and some number of threads dedicated to other tasks (long running/CPU intensive tasks).
It's a console application.

And I want to use async/await in all of the threads but I learned that async/await uses the [managed thread pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool) to run continuation that means requests handling can be delayed because of a bunch of CPU intensive tasks shown up (yes, so many, it's why i have limited threads count to do this job)?

1. If i want to limit concurrency, then i must not use TAP?
2. If i want to do some job in background for aplication's lifetime, then i must not use TAP either?
3. Should I write a ThradPool implementation with it's own SyncronizationContext to do so?
4. Is there an other way to run continuation in some set of threads?

Comment: How about increasing the initial number of threads spawned by the `ThreadPool`, by using the [`SetMinThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads) method? For example `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 10)`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias i don't like this solution because request handling and long running tasks still mixed up in one thread pool which still can lead to case when there is no thread to handle request because all of them is busy with long running tasks.

And i don't really need so many threads for long running tasks (3 is enough for now).

Comment: How about starting the long running tasks with the option [`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions)? Btw when you say "long running" do you mean from start to end of the application, or just lasting for more than a couple of seconds?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias i didn't know about TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, thank you!
A job can last for hours as well as for minutes but they occur until application is stopped.

Comment: The `LongRunning` option is nothing special really. It just runs the task in a new thread instead of a `ThreadPool` thread. My guess is that your long running tasks are actually loops delayed with `Thread.Sleep`. If this is the case then you could replace the `Thread.Sleep` with `await Task.Delay`, and have long running tasks that don't need a dedicated thread. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61192103/async-system-threading-timer-sometimes-throwing-null-exception/61193299#61193299) is an example.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias there is no Thread.Sleep in these tasks, anyway, thank you!

Comment: The tasks are probably not spinning in tight loops for the whole lifetime of the program. I guess that most of the time they are waiting for something. Instead of blocking the current thread, they could wait asynchronously instead, by using the `SemaphoreSlin.WaitAsync` or an async queue like the [`Channel`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/). Honestly it wouldn't make much difference. Wasting 3 threads is just 3 MB of underutilized RAM, which is nothing for a modern computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I want to use async/await in all of the threads but I learned that async/await uses the managed thread pool to run continuation that means requests handling can be delayed because of a bunch of CPU intensive tasks shown up (yes, so many, it's why i have limited threads count to do this job)?

This is a close-enough analysis. Technically, it's not `async`/`await` that needs the thread pool for continuations, but internal TAP method implementations. That said, it is a common pattern in the BCL, and because of this, exhausting the thread pool can cause delays for asynchronous completion.

> If i want to limit concurrency, then i must not use TAP?

As long as you don't overwhelm the thread pool, you can use TAP. Limiting concurrency would free up the thread pool, which will enable TAP.

> If i want to do some job in background for aplication's lifetime, then i must not use TAP either?

I would think of it more as "don't drown the thread pool in work". An exhausted thread pool isn't great for *any* kind of work.

> Should I write a ThradPool implementation with it's own SyncronizationContext to do so?
>   Is there an other way to run continuation in some set of threads?

You can use `SynchronizationContext` to control where `await` resumes executing, but there are still BCL-internal completions that need to queue to the thread pool. There's no controlling that; the only real option is to keep the thread pool free.

Comment: `>As long as you don't overwhelm the thread pool, you can use TAP.`

So, if i receive 1000 job items then i should cache them somewhere and enqueue them as they complete? For now i use infinity loop in sepearate thread to execute these job items (with producer-consumer pattern to enqueue job items to this thread).

Comment: I'm confused. If your job items are already being processed by a dedicated thread, how do you have the problem of thread pool exhaustion in the first place?

Comment: I want to use async/await in all of the threads, i haven't done it yet. I am trying to analyse all possible problems before they occur.

Comment: If you have dedicated threads for your CPU-bound operations, you can use a `SynchronizationContext` for those dedicated threads, and thus keep them from exhausting the thread pool when they use `async`. E.g., `AsyncContext` or `AsyncContextThread` from [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/doc/AsyncContext.md).