# Async System.Threading.Timer sometimes throwing null exception

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, async-await

I am trying to execute a code asynchronously after a certain interval of time and want to check again only after I am done with the code execution to prevent overlapping. For that I am using the following variables and timer code.

```
private System.Threading.Timer _timer;
private int _intervalInMilliSec = 10000;

_timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async (o) =>
{
    // Stop the timer;
    _timer.Change(-1, -1);

    // awaited api call goes here

    // start timer again (BeginTime, Interval)
    _timer.Change(_intervalInMilliSec, _intervalInMilliSec);
}, null, 0, _intervalInMilliSec);
```

Most of the times it is working fine but sometimes rarely I started getting the following exception at the line `_timer.Change(-1, -1);`

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

At that point "o" is showing as null. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Is issue occurring when application starts?   Means you are creating the event before the constructor is called.  Where is the new _timer() code?

Comment: Yes @jdweng I am triggering that code at the application start, when it is working fine, the code inside timer event keeps running after 10 seconds.

Comment: The ASP.NET is meant for serving web requests, not for running as a Windows service. The ASP.NET infrastructure routinely recycles the `AppDomain`, and will cause disruption to the scheduling of the timer you are trying to maintain.

Comment: @jdweng I checked that code again and found that function enclosing the timer code is getting called after the constructor. new _timer() code is "// awaited api call goes here"

Comment: @TheodorZoulias sorry my bad. I mistakenly added asp.net tag. it's a wpf app.

Comment: Tell me how _timer could be a null?  Look at your code.  There is something wrong with the initialization that you are getting to _timer_Change and the timer is null.  It is probably some sort of cross-thread issue.  You may want to add a LOCK so a process change doesn't occur in the middle of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you get the `NullReferenceException` in your code, but I suggest to scrap the `Timer` approach altogether and replace it with a simpler [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) in a loop:

```
var apiCallCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var apiCallTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        var delayTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), apiCallCts.Token);
        await SomeApiCallAsync();
        await delayTask;
    }
});
```

And at the app shutdown:

```
apiCallCts.Cancel();
```

The above solution has a different behavior in case of an API failure. Instead of crashing the app, will silently stop calling the API. This is something that you'll have to consider.

Comment: That null reference exception is still a mystery and I have implemented your solution which is working fine. You are far better (in providing alternative) than the members marking question as off topic and downvoting it. Thanks again :)